# Conditionally collpase Excel rows based on string in column?

Tags: excel, vba, rows, excel-365

I get a large excel sheet on a weekly basis from a project management tool. It features information on certain dates and times for specific tasks. The content changes from week to week. But the structure remains the same. It basically looks like this:

```
+----------+---------------+----------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+----------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------------------------------+---------------+-------------+------------+---------------------------+-------------------+------------------+--------------+-------------------------+---------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------+
|   Type   |      Hub      | Hub (ID) |     Project     | Project (ID) |     Package     | Package (ID) |       Measure        | Measure (ID) | Measure (Tags) | Measure (Phase) |              Activity               | Activity (ID) | Aggregation | To Do/Done |          Comment          |    Responsible    | Responsible (ID) | Start (Plan) | Start (Actual/Forecast) | Start (Delta) | Start (Traffic Light) | Start (Achievement) | End (Plan) |
+----------+---------------+----------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+----------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------------------------------+---------------+-------------+------------+---------------------------+-------------------+------------------+--------------+-------------------------+---------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------+
| Hub      | ABC Comp Demo |      285 | -               |            - | -               |            - | -                    |            - |              - | -               | -                                   |             - | -           | To Do      | -                         | -                 |                - | -            | -                       |             - | -                     |                   - | -          |
| Project  | ABC Comp Demo |      285 | English Example |         1802 | -               |            - | -                    |            - |              - | -               | -                                   |             - | Active      | To Do      | -                         | Friederike Bieser |             1650 | 2020-05-19   | 2020-05-16              |            -3 | Yellow                |               81,00 | 2020-07-26 |
| Package  | ABC Comp Demo |      285 | English Example |         1802 | Working Capital |         9440 | -                    |            - |              - | -               | -                                   |             - | Active      | To Do      | -                         |                   |                  | 2020-05-19   | 2020-05-16              |            -3 | Yellow                |               71,50 | 2020-07-26 |
| Measure  | ABC Comp Demo |      285 | English Example |         1802 | Working Capital |         9440 | Inventory reduction  |        38894 |                | DOI3            | -                                   |             - | Active      | To Do      | -                         |                   |                  | 2020-05-29   | 2020-05-21              |            -8 | Yellow                |               66,67 | 2020-07-05 |
| Activity | ABC Comp Demo |      285 | English Example |         1802 | Working Capital |         9440 | Inventory reduction  |        38894 |                | DOI3            | Adjusting the term of payment       |        131741 | Active      | Done       |                           | Friederike Bieser |             1650 | 2020-05-29   | 2020-05-21              |            -8 | Green                 |              100,00 | 2020-06-05 |
| Activity | ABC Comp Demo |      285 | English Example |         1802 | Working Capital |         9440 | Inventory reduction  |        38894 |                | DOI3            | New controlling cycle               |        131742 | Active      | To Do      |                           | Friederike Bieser |             1650 | 2020-06-09   | 2020-06-06              |            -3 | Green                 |              100,00 | 2020-06-16 |
| Activity | ABC Comp Demo |      285 | English Example |         1802 | Working Capital |         9440 | Inventory reduction  |        38894 |                | DOI3            | ABC analysis                        |        131743 | Active      | To Do      |                           | Friederike Bieser |             1650 | 2020-06-17   | 2020-06-26              |             9 | Red                   |                0,00 | 2020-06-22 |
| Activity | ABC Comp Demo |      285 | English Example |         1802 | Working Capital |         9440 | Inventory reduction  |        38894 |                | DOI3            | Adjust cash discount agreements     |        131744 | Active      | To Do      | All good ...              | Friederike Bieser |             1650 | 2020-06-23   | 2020-06-26              |             3 | Yellow                |               33,33 | 2020-07-01 |
| Activity | ABC Comp Demo |      285 | English Example |         1802 | Working Capital |         9440 | Inventory reduction  |        38894 |                | DOI3            | Sell old stocks                     |        131745 | Active      | To Do      |                           | Friederike Bieser |             1650 | 2020-07-02   | 2020-07-02              |             0 | Green                 |              100,00 | 2020-07-05 |
| Measure  | ABC Comp Demo |      285 | English Example |         1802 | Working Capital |         9440 | Turnover             |        38895 |                | DOI2            | -                                   |             - | Active      | To Do      | -                         |                   |                  | 2020-05-19   | 2020-05-16              |            -3 | Yellow                |               77,78 | 2020-07-26 |
| Activity | ABC Comp Demo |      285 | English Example |         1802 | Working Capital |         9440 | Turnover             |        38895 |                | DOI2            | Inventory                           |        131746 | Active      | Done       |                           | Friederike Bieser |             1650 | 2020-05-19   | 2020-05-16              |            -3 | Green                 |              100,00 | 2020-06-07 |
| Activity | ABC Comp Demo |      285 | English Example |         1802 | Working Capital |         9440 | Turnover             |        38895 |                | DOI2            | Turnover                            |        131747 | Active      | To Do      | Everything is working ... | Friederike Bieser |             1650 | 2020-06-16   | 2020-06-15              |            -1 | Green                 |              100,00 | 2020-06-21 |
| Activity | ABC Comp Demo |      285 | English Example |         1802 | Working Capital |         9440 | Turnover             |        38895 |                | DOI2            | Evaluation of old inventory         |        131748 | Active      | To Do      |                           | Friederike Bieser |             1650 | 2020-06-22   | 2020-06-28              |             6 | Yellow                |               33,33 | 2020-06-27 |
| Activity | ABC Comp Demo |      285 | English Example |         1802 | Working Capital |         9440 | Turnover             |        38895 |                | DOI2            | Sell of old inventory               |        131749 | Active      | To Do      |                           | Friederike Bieser |             1650 | 2020-06-27   | 2020-07-03              |             6 | Yellow                |               33,33 | 2020-07-04 |
| Activity | ABC Comp Demo |      285 | English Example |         1802 | Working Capital |         9440 | Turnover             |        38895 |                | DOI2            | Allocation of storage areas         |        131750 | Active      | To Do      | Risk ...                  | Friederike Bieser |             1650 | 2020-07-05   | 2020-07-02              |            -3 | Green                 |              100,00 | 2020-07-15 |
| Activity | ABC Comp Demo |      285 | English Example |         1802 | Working Capital |         9440 | Turnover             |        38895 |                | DOI2            | Integration of SAP in storage areas |        131751 | Active      | To Do      |                           | Friederike Bieser |             1650 | 2020-07-18   | 2020-07-20              |             2 | Green                 |              100,00 | 2020-07-26 |
| Package  | ABC Comp Demo |      285 | English Example |         1802 | Production      |         9441 | -                    |            - |              - | -               | -                                   |             - | Active      | To Do      | -                         |                   |                  | 2020-05-29   | 2020-06-03              |             5 | Yellow                |               86,00 | 2020-07-13 |
| Measure  | ABC Comp Demo |      285 | English Example |         1802 | Production      |         9441 | Machinery hall       |        38896 |                | DOI3            | -                                   |             - | Active      | To Do      | -                         |                   |                  | 2020-05-29   | 2020-06-03              |             5 | Yellow                |               86,67 | 2020-07-13 |
| Activity | ABC Comp Demo |      285 | English Example |         1802 | Production      |         9441 | Machinery hall       |        38896 |                | DOI3            | Sell milling cutter long            |        131752 | Active      | Done       | All good ...              | Friederike Bieser |             1650 | 2020-05-29   | 2020-06-03              |             5 | Yellow                |               33,33 | 2020-06-03 |
| Activity | ABC Comp Demo |      285 | English Example |         1802 | Production      |         9441 | Machinery hall       |        38896 |                | DOI3            | Sell extruder                       |        131753 | Active      | To Do      |                           | Friederike Bieser |             1650 | 2020-06-20   | 2020-06-17              |            -3 | Green                 |              100,00 | 2020-06-25 |
| Activity | ABC Comp Demo |      285 | English Example |         1802 | Production      |         9441 | Machinery hall       |        38896 |                | DOI3            | Purchase milling machine 34DDe      |        131754 | Active      | To Do      |                           | Friederike Bieser |             1650 | 2020-06-26   | 2020-06-26              |             0 | Green                 |              100,00 | 2020-06-30 |
| Activity | ABC Comp Demo |      285 | English Example |         1802 | Production      |         9441 | Machinery hall       |        38896 |                | DOI3            | Introduction milling machine 34DDe  |        131755 | Active      | To Do      | Risk ...                  | Friederike Bieser |             1650 | 2020-07-01   | 2020-07-02              |             1 | Green                 |              100,00 | 2020-07-02 |
| Activity | ABC Comp Demo |      285 | English Example |         1802 | Production      |         9441 | Machinery hall       |        38896 |                | DOI3            | Evaluation                          |        131756 | Active      | To Do      |                           | Friederike Bieser |             1650 | 2020-07-03   | 2020-06-30              |            -3 | Green                 |              100,00 | 2020-07-13 |
| Package  | ABC Comp Demo |      285 | English Example |         1802 | Procurement     |         9442 | -                    |            - |              - | -               | -                                   |             - | Active      | To Do      | -                         |                   |                  | 2020-05-24   | 2020-05-24              |             0 | Yellow                |               86,00 | 2020-07-22 |
| Measure  | ABC Comp Demo |      285 | English Example |         1802 | Procurement     |         9442 | Diversification      |        38897 |                | DOI1            | -                                   |             - | Active      | To Do      | -                         |                   |                  | 2020-05-24   | 2020-05-24              |             0 | Yellow                |               86,67 | 2020-07-22 |
| Activity | ABC Comp Demo |      285 | English Example |         1802 | Procurement     |         9442 | Diversification      |        38897 |                | DOI1            | ABC analysis                        |        131757 | Active      | Done       | All good ...              | Friederike Bieser |             1650 | 2020-05-24   | 2020-05-24              |             0 | Green                 |              100,00 | 2020-06-06 |
| Activity | ABC Comp Demo |      285 | English Example |         1802 | Procurement     |         9442 | Diversification      |        38897 |                | DOI1            | Value Network with Meyer Company    |        131758 | Active      | To Do      |                           | Friederike Bieser |             1650 | 2020-06-14   | 2020-06-14              |             0 | Green                 |              100,00 | 2020-06-22 |
| Activity | ABC Comp Demo |      285 | English Example |         1802 | Procurement     |         9442 | Diversification      |        38897 |                | DOI1            | Renegotiation                       |        131759 | Active      | To Do      |                           | Friederike Bieser |             1650 | 2020-06-23   | 2020-06-28              |             5 | Yellow                |               33,33 | 2020-07-13 |
| Activity | ABC Comp Demo |      285 | English Example |         1802 | Procurement     |         9442 | Diversification      |        38897 |                | DOI1            | Meeting                             |        131760 | Active      | To Do      |                           | Friederike Bieser |             1650 | 2020-07-14   | 2020-07-12              |            -2 | Green                 |              100,00 | 2020-07-19 |
| Activity | ABC Comp Demo |      285 | English Example |         1802 | Procurement     |         9442 | Diversification      |        38897 |                | DOI1            | Product group concept               |        131761 | Active      | To Do      |                           | Friederike Bieser |             1650 | 2020-07-20   | 2020-07-20              |             0 | Green                 |              100,00 | 2020-07-22 |
| Measure  | ABC Comp Demo |      285 | English Example |         1802 | Procurement     |         9442 | Supplier Negotiation |        38898 |                |                 | -                                   |             - | Paused      |            | -                         |                   |                             
+----------+---------------+----------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+----------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------------------------------+---------------+-------------+------------+---------------------------+-------------------+------------------+--------------+-------------------------+---------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------+
```

Is there a way to conditionally collapse rows based on the string in column `Type`?  I want all rows with the string `Activity` in the column `Type` to be collapsed.

It would be great if you could help me out! Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

- This is what the result should look like:

[image]

- Filtering is not an option. The column `Type` has certain hierarchy to it, which does not allow for simple filtering without losing information.
- I am using the current Excel version in the 365 Environment

Comment: Why not simply set a filter?

Comment: Good point! The `Type` column has a hierarchy to it. Each `Activity` is a part of the nearest `Measure` above. Filtering for `Activity` results in losing this hierarchy. In addition... management specifically asks for a grouping/collapsing...

Comment: Have a summary sheet and bring the data for the type selected to see only that detail.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not a solution either. I need it colapsed. It's asked for.

Comment: Have you tried using [TreeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.cubefield.treeviewcontrol)?

Comment: Nope... how would that work

Comment: A main heading of 'activity' with all the local activities (between two measures) grouped together. Autofilter appears to grab the whole column, and doesn't leave any evidence at all, so is probably not useful.

Comment: Can you show how the result should looks like? And tell uns which Excel Version do you use.

Comment: Hi all, I just added, how the result should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this VBA-Code

```
Sub Group_Activity()

' Groups all rows with "Activity" in Column "A"
Dim cell As Range
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim startrow As Long
Dim endrow As Long

startrow = -1
endrow = -1

    With ActiveSheet

        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For Each cell In .Range("A1:A" & lastrow)
            'Debug.Print Trim(cell.Value)
            If Trim(cell.Value) <> "Activity" Then
                If startrow > 0 Then
                    .Rows(startrow & ":" & endrow).Group
                    startrow = -1
                    endrow = -1
                End If

            Else
                If startrow = -1 Then startrow = cell.Row
                endrow = cell.Row

            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

brings this result without any selection process:
[image]

Comment: Different approach! .. Good one. You can comment out `Debug.Print Trim(cell.Value)`

Comment: Yes thats true, I forgot it after testing my code :-)

Answer (score 2):

Select column A and find (Control + F) "Activity" .. Select Match entire cell contents --> Click "Find All" --> Press Control + A to select all the ranges in the list in the dialogue box.

[image]

Press Control + 9 to hide the rows or run the following procedure.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim ActGrps As Range
    Set ActGrps = Selection
    Dim ar As Range
    For Each ar In ActGrps.Areas
    ar.Rows.Group
    ar.Rows.Hidden = True
    Next
End Sub
```

There can be a longer procedure to completely automate all this with a command button selecting the "Activity" cells and grouping the rows.

To show and hide all rows at once - Select the data A Column (In this case A1:A32). Click on Data Menu --> Outline --> Show/Hide details.
Similarly, you can also ungroup all the data at once with Menu --> Outline --> Ungroup --> Rows.

To Show or hide a particular group use handle on the left with Row numbers.

**EDIT**
Following is the procedure added as per comments below.

```
Public fndAdd As String
'========================================================================
Sub GroupRowsWithCondition()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ActiveSheet
Dim DataCol As Range
Set DataCol = sh.Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
'Debug.Print DataCol.Address '$A$1:$A$31

Dim cl As Range, fnd As Range
    For Each cl In DataCol
    If cl = "Activity" Then
        If fnd Is Nothing Then
        Set fnd = cl
        Else
        Set fnd = Union(fnd, cl)
        End If
    End If
    Next
'Debug.Print fnd.Address '$A$6:$A$10,$A$12:$A$17,$A$20:$A$24,$A$27:$A$31

fndAdd = fnd.Address

Dim ar As Range
For Each ar In fnd.Areas
ar.Rows.Group
'ar.Rows.Hidden = True
Next

Range("A1").Select
End Sub
'========================================================================

Sub toggleGroupShowHide()
'If assigned to form control button on a sheet,
' this macro will show / hide rows of the group created in GroupRowsWithCondition procedure
With ActiveSheet.Range(fndAdd)
    If .Rows.Hidden = True Then
        .Rows.Hidden = False
    Else
        .Rows.Hidden = True
    End If
End With

End Sub
'========================================================================
```

It is recommended to avoid ActiveSheet and use sheet name instead. So, `Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")` is better then `Set sh = ActiveSheet`

You can insert a button on the sheet using Developer menu --> Controls --> Insert --> Form Controls --> Button and assign the macro to the button. But consider this if this macro is used frequently.

[image]

Comment: Great way forward! I would love to have a fully automated version. Other users will work with it, too. So that would be great. Do you reckon that it would be possible for you to help me out with thaz?